# Should we contains test statements in code?

Tags: java, python, c++, c

I know the question is not related to technology,is about the code style and standard.

I have just studied programming for 1 year,and so many people tell me that "you should test any single part of your program rather than code all then test".But they forgot to say whether we should delete test statements when officially released?

I hear several different voice:

1. It makes your code looks bloated,so delete it.
2. You shouldn't delete it if you want to modify something later.
3. You can delete it,but you must write some comment if needed.

A simple code contains test just like this:(the real code won't as easy as it,and the example may be a bit bad)

```c
void Function(){
    printf("hello,world");
}

int main(){
//  Function();
    return 0;
}
```

So my question is should we delete it ?The result is like this:

```c
void Function(){
    printf("hello,world");
}
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is not how tests are supposed to work. Tests are being invoked during the build process and use individual units of your actual code (thus called unit tests). Testing code usually resides outside the scope of your actual code (such as `src/test` vs `src/main` in maven projects). None of your testing code should reside in the actual code. If you have to comment out your testing code, there's something wrong.

Comment: Note that you can have your cake and eat it too: the [Rust programming language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/testing.html) allows you to put testing functions next to their implementations. The compiler is smart enough to only compile the test code when you run `cargo test`

Comment: Modifying code to test it pretty much defeats the purpose of testing. How do you know your test modification is not a fix for a problem? In real life programming, tests are completely separate entity (file/group of files). Customer gets production code, developers use production code + tests code to verify correctness.

Comment: There's informal testing that you do when programming and that part isn't usually worth preserving. Then there's formal tests written as separate code. How to use the latter mainly depends on the product and the organization's work flow. In some cases it makes sense to have the tests together with the code ("TDD"), in other cases you aren't allowed to have any tests in production code, in which case you might want to handle tests as a separate branch in version control. And so on... I don't think there's a general method that fits every product.

Comment: imho your example is suboptimal to illustrate what you actually mean. Neither does `// Function();` test anything (it is a comment) nor is an empty `main` your final code (testing is removed but also everything else). In any case, "testing" is more than merely calling a function

Answer (score 5):

This is not what they mean by testing code though.

Instead you write separate test function for each part of your code, that can run independently of your main code. Then use a test-runner ( `pytest`, `unittest` or `nose` are the most popular) to run your tests.

Example, say your main code has a function like this:

```
def add_numbers(a,b):
   return a+b
```

and your main is like this:

```
def main():
    x = 4
    y = 5
    z = add_numbers(x,y)
    #print(z)  <-- dont do this
```

instead you create a new function, often in a new file:

```
def test_add_numbers():
    a=200
    b=343
    res = add_numbers(a,b)
    assert res == 543
```

Test runners will then run all your tests and output if any one of them doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

When officially released the code base should have unit tests written and everytime you make a change, those unit tests should pass.

Tests should not be written like you are writing, they should use pytest etc.

Comment: While that sentence is correct, you should elaborate way more on this. At this stage, this hardly counts as an answer.

Comment: OP is not questioning whether to write tests (or if they are required to pass before release) or not. I'd say that this is definitely not an answer to the question.